# Is it necessary to use logical properties when values for all sides are the same?

Tags: css

Is it necessary to use logical properties instead of for example `margin: 0;`?

Like

```
margin-block: 0;
margin-inline: 0;
```

Is there a requirement to use logical properties in this case or is it ok to just use `margin: 0;`?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it necessary to use logical properties instead of for example margin: 0;?

No, since in all the cases you will have the same result. It's even better to use `margin:0` to have better browser support.